# Mikrotik. Router OS. IPTV image freezes after 3-5 minutes since channel switching

Tags: mikrotik-routeros, iptv, igmp

In order to unfreeze I have to switch channel. Here's the config:

```
add admin-mac=48:33:5A:3D:4E:84 auto-mac=no comment=defconf igmp-snooping=yes \
    name=bridge
/interface pppoe-client
add add-default-route=yes disabled=no interface=ether1 name=pppoe-out1 \
    password=abcxyz123 use-peer-dns=yes user=abcxyz123
/interface wireless
set [ find default-name=wlan1 ] band=2ghz-b/g/n channel-width=20/40mhz-XX \
    distance=indoors frequency=auto installation=indoor mode=ap-bridge ssid=\
    MikroTik-3D8E88 wireless-protocol=802.11
set [ find default-name=wlan2 ] band=5ghz-a/n/ac channel-width=20/40/80mhz-XXXX \
    disabled=no distance=indoors frequency=auto installation=indoor mode=\
    ap-bridge ssid=CosmicFruits wireless-protocol=802.11
/interface list
add comment=defconf name=WAN
add comment=defconf name=LAN
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] authentication-types=wpa2-psk mode=dynamic-keys \
    supplicant-identity=MikroTik wpa-pre-shared-key=ABCXYZ123 \
    wpa2-pre-shared-key=ABCXYZ123
/ip hotspot profile
set [ find default=yes ] html-directory=flash/hotspot
/ip pool
add name=dhcp ranges=192.168.88.10-192.168.88.254
/ip dhcp-server
add address-pool=dhcp disabled=no interface=bridge name=defconf
/interface bridge filter
add action=drop chain=output out-interface=wlan2 packet-type=multicast
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=ether2
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=ether3
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=ether4
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=ether5
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=wlan1
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=wlan2
/ip neighbor discovery-settings
set discover-interface-list=LAN
/interface list member
add comment=defconf interface=bridge list=LAN
add comment=defconf interface=ether1 list=WAN
add interface=pppoe-out1 list=WAN
/ip address
add address=192.168.88.1/24 comment=defconf interface=ether2 network=\
    192.168.88.0
add address=1.0.0.1/30 interface=ether1 network=1.0.0.0
/ip dhcp-client
add comment=defconf interface=ether1
/ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.88.0/24 comment=defconf gateway=192.168.88.1
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes
/ip dns static
add address=192.168.88.1 comment=defconf name=router.lan type=A
/ip firewall filter
add action=accept chain=input comment=\
    "defconf: accept established,related,untracked" connection-state=\
    established,related,untracked
add action=accept chain=forward comment="ALLOW IGMP" in-interface=ether1 \
    protocol=udp
add action=accept chain=forward in-interface=ether1 protocol=igmp
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=\
    invalid
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept ICMP" protocol=icmp
add action=accept chain=input comment=\
    "defconf: accept to local loopback (for CAPsMAN)" dst-address=127.0.0.1
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop all not coming from LAN" \
    in-interface-list=!LAN
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept in ipsec policy" \
    ipsec-policy=in,ipsec
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept out ipsec policy" \
    ipsec-policy=out,ipsec
add action=fasttrack-connection chain=forward comment="defconf: fasttrack" \
    connection-state=established,related
add action=accept chain=forward comment=\
    "defconf: accept established,related, untracked" connection-state=\
    established,related,untracked
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=\
    invalid
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop all from WAN not DSTNATed" \
    connection-nat-state=!dstnat connection-state=new in-interface-list=WAN
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="defconf: masquerade" ipsec-policy=\
    out,none out-interface-list=WAN
/ipv6 firewall address-list
add address=::/128 comment="defconf: unspecified address" list=bad_ipv6
add address=::1/128 comment="defconf: lo" list=bad_ipv6
add address=fec0::/10 comment="defconf: site-local" list=bad_ipv6
add address=::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 comment="defconf: ipv4-mapped" list=bad_ipv6
add address=::/96 comment="defconf: ipv4 compat" list=bad_ipv6
add address=100::/64 comment="defconf: discard only " list=bad_ipv6
add address=2001:db8::/32 comment="defconf: documentation" list=bad_ipv6
add address=2001:10::/28 comment="defconf: ORCHID" list=bad_ipv6
add address=3ffe::/16 comment="defconf: 6bone" list=bad_ipv6
add address=::224.0.0.0/100 comment="defconf: other" list=bad_ipv6
add address=::127.0.0.0/104 comment="defconf: other" list=bad_ipv6
add address=::/104 comment="defconf: other" list=bad_ipv6
add address=::255.0.0.0/104 comment="defconf: other" list=bad_ipv6
/ipv6 firewall filter
add action=accept chain=input comment=\
    "defconf: accept established,related,untracked" connection-state=\
    established,related,untracked
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=\
    invalid
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept ICMPv6" protocol=icmpv6
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept UDP traceroute" port=\
    33434-33534 protocol=udp
add action=accept chain=input comment=\
    "defconf: accept DHCPv6-Client prefix delegation." dst-port=546 protocol=\
    udp src-address=fe80::/10
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept IKE" dst-port=500,4500 \
    protocol=udp
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept ipsec AH" protocol=\
    ipsec-ah
add action=accept chain=input comment="defconf: accept ipsec ESP" protocol=\
    ipsec-esp
add action=accept chain=input comment=\
    "defconf: accept all that matches ipsec policy" ipsec-policy=in,ipsec
add action=drop chain=input comment=\
    "defconf: drop everything else not coming from LAN" in-interface-list=!LAN
add action=accept chain=forward comment=\
    "defconf: accept established,related,untracked" connection-state=\
    established,related,untracked
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=\
    invalid
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop packets with bad src ipv6" \
    src-address-list=bad_ipv6
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop packets with bad dst ipv6" \
    dst-address-list=bad_ipv6
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: rfc4890 drop hop-limit=1" \
    hop-limit=equal:1 protocol=icmpv6
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept ICMPv6" protocol=\
    icmpv6
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept HIP" protocol=139
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept IKE" dst-port=500,4500 \
    protocol=udp
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept ipsec AH" protocol=\
    ipsec-ah
add action=accept chain=forward comment="defconf: accept ipsec ESP" protocol=\
    ipsec-esp
add action=accept chain=forward comment=\
    "defconf: accept all that matches ipsec policy" ipsec-policy=in,ipsec
add action=drop chain=forward comment=\
    "defconf: drop everything else not coming from LAN" in-interface-list=!LAN
/routing igmp-proxy
set quick-leave=yes
/routing igmp-proxy interface
add alternative-subnets=0.0.0.0/0 interface=ether1 upstream=yes
add
/system clock
set time-zone-name=Asia/Dushanbe
/tool mac-server
set allowed-interface-list=LAN
/tool mac-server mac-winbox
set allowed-interface-list=LAN
```

And no logs are appearing after freezing/unfreezing.

Comment: What makes you think this problem is caused by Mikrotik/RouterOS?

Comment: Debug with GNS3

Comment: From what I understand, you can view the current state of IGMP-Proxy. I suggest you check whether it correctly picks up the transmission and all and if it is dropped later.

Comment: Ok, how do I do that? Which metrics should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by disabling all the denying rules in IP->Firewall (I don't know which exactly makes this problem)